# OpenCV 3.1.0: Finding the 3D position of a flat plane with known dimensions

Tags: python, opencv, math, 3d

I have a flat quadrilateral plane that I know the dimensions of, and I can find the contours of it, along with the 4 corners. **I need assistance in figuring out the method of determining its 3D position.** I have managed to get a 3x3 perspective transform of it, which looks something like this:

```
[[  3.91873630e-02   1.20990983e+00  -2.81213415e+02]
 [  1.21202027e+00  -1.85962357e-15  -3.52697898e+02]
 [  3.83991908e-04   2.52680041e-05   1.00000000e+00]]
```

*(this is OpenCV 3.1.0, in python, and that matrix is just one frame, so it might not be representative of all potential orientations)*

Can I determine the angle away from the camera and distance from the camera from this information, or do I need to perform more calculations?

I'm not sure what you guys need to know, so I'll be happy to give you more information if you need it?

Comment: you can use cv::solvePnP

Answer (score 1):

You can use solvePnP function to determine quadrilateral's position and orientation wrt camera.

All you need to have is

- 3D coordinates of quadrilateral's corners in world frame
- corresponding pixel coordinates
- Camera's intrinsic parameters

You can directly use [solvepnp()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#bool%20solvePnP(InputArray%20objectPoints,%20InputArray%20imagePoints,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArray%20rvec,%20OutputArray%20tvec,%20bool%20useExtrinsicGuess,%20int%20flags)) function of Opencv.

In output you get pose of world coordinate system in camera coordinate system. If you take world as quadrilateral itself, you get pose information(Rotation and translation) of quadrilateral in camera coordinate system

---

```
C++: bool solvePnP(InputArray objectPoints, InputArray imagePoints, 
                   InputArray cameraMatrix, InputArray distCoeffs, 
                   OutputArray rvec, OutputArray tvec, 
                   bool useExtrinsicGuess=false, int flags=ITERATIVE );
```

Use CV_P3P argument for flags, in case you have exactly 4 points.

Comment: I'll look into this and potentially accept it as the answer. Thanks!